# Android + Robolectric: смысл @Config

Tags: android, robolectric

Коллеги, приветствую.
Потребовалось разрабатывать автотесты android-приложения, пристыковал Robolectric.
Прошу, поясните популярно: в чем смысл константы в аннотации @Config?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С ее помощью можно быстро и легко наруливать конфиг (как ни странно) своего теста.
К примеру:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP, 
            manifest = "app/src/main/")
public class MainActivityTest {
    ...
}
```

`constants` обязателен и содержит в себе константы вашего приложения, такие как тип билда (debug, relise), версию, пакет приложения ("ru.whalemare.myapp" к примеру) и т.д.

`sdk` опционален, и указывает какую версию Android необходимо будет эмулировать. Т.е. в какой среде будут запускаться тесты.

`manifest` также опционален и нужен, если к примеру, для тестов вам нужны какие-то особые разрешения. Так я например лечил ошибку с библиотекой UiAutomator

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>
```